# Joomla 2.5 / use article title as "Browser Page Title" but dont display titles on articles

Tags: html, joomla

At the beginning of the week I migrated a website from Joomla 1.5 to 2.5, the first thing I had to do was disable page titles so they didn't appear on the actual article at the top.

But on Joomla 1.5 I had the article title displaying as the Browser Page Title so the actual "< title >" in head, not on the top of the content of the article.

Now I see there is a way to set this manually under each menu item under the "Page Display Options" > "Browser Page Title"

But is there a setting to display the article title automatically as the browser page title instead of manually entering each one as to me this sort of defeats the purpose of putting a title on articles in the first place, for me anyway.

Hopefully someone can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem here: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2662239#p2661844

It appears a template over ride seems to work fine for this issue apart from the "Home" button of my menu which I suspect its to do with it being a featured article.

Comment: The guy who wrote that forum post really knows his stuff.